I accidently deleted entire disk with my OS
But I have .iso backup of my root folder. What should I do in this situation?
(P.S. I used the dd program for restore my /dev/sda3 partition, but what should I do with efi partition (necessary) and swap (not necessary)?

If you have ESP, you can just totally reinstall grub. You probably need to update fstab with new UUID as it would have old UUID from now deleted ESP. You can add swap partition if desired and also then update UUID in fstab's mount of swap. If you do not update UUIDs you will have boot issues. Probably easiest with live installer. First mount & edit fstab & then use advanced mode to fully reinstall grub. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

How a system boots is determined by device firmware; ie. either a MBR is required (1982 IBM PC & later compatibles) or an ESP will be used; both of which are stored outside of the root or / partition. Do note /root/ folder is only a user directory and differs to the / or root directory!    In your case I'd restore your backup, see if it boots, then likely non-destructively re-install over it a fresh Ubuntu system keeping old data & settings etc (Ubuntu product & release details matter & you didn't provide any; only stating Ubuntu)

Easiest option will be to reinstall ubuntu and reinstall your favorite programs.
You can later copy data from the iso backup.

But I need to restore my settings and desktop. I need to fully restore my OS from this image

Can I reinstall the OS and replace new /dev/sda3 with my old /dev/sda3?

Yes, you can do that, you will need to edit /etc/fstab accordingly.

You seem to be flailing about with tools you don't understand, on disks you don't understand, to achieve a poorly specified task you don't understand.  Slow down, do a breathing exercise, and explain the "accidentally deleted entire disk with my OS" part. Your problem may not be as bad as you think (but it could be worse).

Thanks to everyone who answered!

Well, I just installed ubuntu and copied my data from backup image, configured fstab and then installed grub, but grub can't boot ubuntu (it starts with shell instead of boot options)
Upd: I created ubuntu boot entry on my second OS loader
Thanks to everyone who helped me

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
